# Windows Azure Notification Hub Error

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have just gotten this error.  Everything was working fine up until this morning.

Error: 400 - The request api-version is invalid because the the notification hub was created in an older version. Re-create the notification hub.

TrackingId:aaed084f-8c8a-49f1-8246-122763437b63_G7,TimeStamp:5/15/2016 3:56:13 AM"

In my node.js table script I am connecting to the hub like so:

```
var azure = require('azure');

var hub = azure.createNotificationHubService('hubName','connectionString');
```

And sending like so:

```
hub.wns.sendRaw(['public'], JSON.stringify(item), function(error){
    if(!error)
        console.log("total refresh " + JSON.stringify(item));
    else
       console.log("error sending total refresh " + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

The error response keeps firing. I tried recreating the notification hub but still get the same error.

Does anybody know why?  Have Microsoft updated their systems?  Do I need to include an update for my javascript windows store application?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that nodejs sdk doesn't set the api-version at all :)
You can temporarily fix this by commenting these lines in the azure-sb module (or fix it in better way somehow):

azure-sb/lib/servicebusserviceclient.js @ line 67:

```
// Set API version
//  if (webResource.queryString[Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY] === undefined) {
        webResource.withQueryOption(Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY, Constants.ServiceBusConstants.CURRENT_API_VERSION);
// } else if (webResource.queryString[Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY] === null) {
//   delete webResource.queryString[Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY];
// }
```

Anyway, waiting for Microsoft to fix this dumb error...

Comment: Thanks for this Peter! For anyone with Mobile Services (not App Service) you can get to this file by loading https://[MobileServiceName].scm.azure-mobile.net/DebugConsole in your browser. This is the Kudu admin interface to your Mobile Service.

Navigate to D :\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\node_modules\azure-sb\lib by clicking one directory at a time above the console window. Then click the pencil icon next to servicebusserviceclient.js. Comment out the if block, leaving the line as Peter described. Then save the file and restart your Mobile Service.

Answer (score 0):

Yah, thanks @Peter.
I created temp module in root "azure-sb-temp", imported instead of "azure" in my notification service, installed packages "azure-common" and "underscore". The last thing is comment @ line 69, 71, 72, 73 at /azure-sb-temp/lib/servicebusserviceclient.js