# Azure Mobile Apps Node.js Backend - Push Notification Error Status Code 400

Tags: ios, node.js, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure with node.js as backend and iOS as client.
I have create an Custom API to push and I have been succeed to send push notification from API to iOS client lately. but now it is strength when  call to my API again it show error message like below :

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": "400",
     "detail": "The request api-version is invalid because the the notification hub was created in an older version. Re-create the notification hub..TrackingId:b90a05a5-c9db-4ad1-81f0-84c309e191f8_G2,TimeStamp:5/15/2016 12:40:41 PM",
     "statusCode": 400
    }
}
```

I already do install azure node.js again, azure-mobile-apps too but no luck still having this issue.

Any advice or solution to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm forgot to inform, i am able to test send push notification on the portal but still can't on my API.

Answer (score 1):

There are same issues with you which suddenly occurred these day.

You can manually modify the sdk source code via Kudu Console site or Visual Studio online extension:

Navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure\node_modules\azure-sb\lib` of your Mobile App directory on Azure.

modify `servicebusserviceclient.js` at line 67, comment out the if block, expect the line 69：

```
  //if (webResource.queryString[Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY] === undefined) {
    webResource.withQueryOption(Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY, Constants.ServiceBusConstants.CURRENT_API_VERSION);
  //} else if (webResource.queryString[Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY] === null) {
  //  delete webResource.queryString[Constants.ServiceBusConstants.API_VERSION_QUERY_KEY];
  //}
```

The same issue refer to [Windows Azure Notification Hub Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234483/windows-azure-notification-hub-error) and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad691999-8c40-4be0-8b6f-34edc8d9c4bc/windows-azure-notification-hub-error?forum=notificationhubs.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thank you for your guidence it is works perfectly. my push notification is running now.